# How to solve domain & subdomain issue in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: configuration, joomla, dns, subdomain, joomla1.5

I have a Joomla 1.5 site published on *http://domain.com/subdomain*. Now I have added a subdomain using the host provider (Yahoo Small Business) that points to the *subdomain* folder:

> subdomain.domain.com points to domain.com/subdomain

*domain.com/subdomain* works fine, but when I go to *subdomain.domain.com*, only the menu shows (but not formatted) on a black background. When I click an item it goes to *http://subdomain.domain.com/subdomain/index.php/clicked-item* and gives me a 404 error. (**[Edit 1]** Shouldn't it be something like *http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/clicked-item*? When I manually enter *http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/clicked-item* again I'm welcomed with a 404.)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**[Edit 2]**

I've deactivated *Search Engine Friendly URLs* and this is the behavior now:

- still when I go to *subdomain.domain.com*, only the menu shows (but not formatted) on a black background;
- still when I click an item it goes to *http://subdomain.domain.com/subdomain/index.php/clicked-item-and-stuff* and gives me a 404 error;
- but when I manually enter *http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/clicked-item-and-stuff* it shows me the requested page, but without any formatting.

**[Edit 3]**

Please have in mind that I'm using Yahoo Small Business which doesn't allow *.htaccess*.

Until I find a proper solution, I'm just using a hack: *subdomain.domain.com* points to *domain.com/another-subdomain* which redirects to *domain.com/subdomain* where Joomla is installed.

Comment: did you create a proper sub-domain or did you just create a folder in the ftp?

Comment: I've created a folder called _subdomain_ in the FTP and then created a sub-domain (i.e., _subdomain.domain.com_) that points to _domain.com/subdomain_. I've done this before with static content sites and there was no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your configuration.php file in your root to ensure the live_site parameter is set to your correct base url e.g. subdomain.domain.com

Comment: Yes, that was it! The parameter was set to _domain.com/subdomain_. Now I've changed it to _subdomain.domain.com_ and it works fine. Thanks.